# How can I customize the color of Python dictionary keys in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to modify the color of the keys in a Python dictionary using the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` and `textMateRules` on the settings.json file for VS Code, to no avail.

Changing `string.quoted.single.python` will modify all python strings, hence me wondering if I can specifically modify the key colors.

The result I want to achieve is similar to how a JSON file looks, even though keys are strings, the colors are different. I currently have the Dark Modern theme so the keys and values have the same color and I do not want to change themes.

e.g.

```
python_dictionary = {
    "Foo": "hello world",
    "Bar": "Baz"
}
```

"Foo" & "Bar" would have different colors

Comment: what are the TextMate scopes of the key string and the value string, if the same you are out of luck

Comment: they are both `string.quoted.single.python`

Comment: you can try **Highlight** and search `string followed by :` and color the string

Answer (score 0):

When I use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command, I don't see any scopes or semantic tokens for Python dictionary keys (I have the Python extension enabled). And looking at [VS Code's builtin TextMate grammar for Python at the time of this writing (version 1.78.2)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.78.2/extensions/python/syntaxes/MagicPython.tmLanguage.json), I don't see any anything that looks like what you're looking for (<kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> for "dict"). I can't think of any workarounds based on using TextMate selectors and the given TextMate grammar.

There's a possibility you could cook something up using an extension such as [`fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.

Otherwise, I think you'll either need to

- [Write a feature-request for VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) to add a TextMate scope for Python dictionary keys.
- or [Write a feature-request for the VS Code Python extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new?assignees=&labels=classify%2C+feature-request&projects=&template=3_feature_request.md) asking them to add a semantic tokens for Python dictionary keys.

Note that strings aren't the only thing that can be a dict key in Python. From [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any immutable type; strings and numbers can always be keys. Tuples can be used as keys if they contain only strings, numbers, or tuples; if a tuple contains any mutable object either directly or indirectly, it cannot be used as a key.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.